# Image testing with network_image_mock package in Flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-test, widget-test-flutter

I'm trying to test a widget that has a `Image.network` child.

The following log is provided.

```
══╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY IMAGE RESOURCE SERVICE ╞════════════════════════════════════════════════════
The following _CastError was thrown resolving an image codec:
type 'Null' is not a subtype of type 'List<int>' in type cast

When the exception was thrown, this was the stack:
#1      _MockHttpResponse.drain (package:flutter_test/src/_binding_io.dart:364:22)
#2      NetworkImage._loadAsync (package:flutter/src/painting/_network_image_io.dart:99:24)
<asynchronous suspension>
<asynchronous suspension>
(elided 2 frames from dart:async and package:stack_trace)
```

My test:

```
testWidgets('My new test', (WidgetTester tester) async {
    mockNetworkImagesFor(() async {
      await tester.pumpWidget(
        MaterialApp(
          home: Scaffold(
            body: ScreenWidget(),
          ),
        ),
      );

      final myImageFinder = find.byKey(const Key('TheImageWidget'));

      expect(myImageFinder, findsOneWidget);

    });
  });
```

In the above sample of code, `ScreenWidget` has a child that is `Image.network`.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

There is no return on you widget, so the list where you call it still empty and flutter don't like it.